# Getting Google's Smarty Pins background animation

Tags: css, html, google-maps

I'm developing a website related to property which has a lot to do with maps. I just browsed to one of the Google's master pieces (i must say that) [Smarty Pins](http://smartypins.withgoogle.com/).

I was just wondering if i can use that (or something like that) background effect in my website. If anybody has any idea how can i achieve that please help me.
Is it legal if i copy them??

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.purchase.edu%2Fjeanine.meyer%2Fgames%2Fmaps%2Ffindgamejavascriptgooglemaps.doc&ei=8RG4VOOXIof0yASKroHwDA&usg=AFQjCNFItcF9AZXruLDhej1uxkssdyyoFg) for a documented tutorial of how to develop a game using Google Maps using HTML, CSS and Javascript. And this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/custom-interactive-maps-with-the-google-maps-api) will guide you though a course for game development in your web app with Google Map in it.

Hope this would Help you in developing a small game in your Website which has Google Maps and make it more interactive.

All the Best!!